# Entity Framework Composite Foreign Key and Navigational Property not being populated in entity during an Include

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

There are two entities pointing to a legacy database, the main entity should take in the secondary entity using an Include and eager load the data.  Unfortunately, **the entity comes up null even though SQL Profiling demonstrates the additional field data is selected properly**.

**Part Entity**

```
[Table("pt_mstr")]
public class QadPart
{
    public QadPart()
    {
        this.PartGroup = new QadPartGroup();
    }

    [Column("pt_part", Order = 0), Key]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    [Column("pt_group", Order = 0), ForeignKey("PartGroup")]
    public string PartGroupCode { get; set; }

    [Column("pt_domain", Order = 1), ForeignKey("PartGroup"), Key]
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    public QadPartGroup PartGroup { get; set; }
}
```

**PartGroup Entity**

```
[Table("PartGroups")]
public class QadPartGroup
{
    [Column("code_value", Order = 0), Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Column("code_cmmt")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("code_domain", Order = 1), Key]
    public string Domain { get; set; }
}
```

pt_mstr in the part entity is a SQL table.
PartGroups in the partgroup entity is a sql view.

The part entity has a composite key (pt_part, pt_domain).
The partgroup entity has a composite key (code_value, code_domain).

**Linq Query**

```
var data = db.Parts.Include<QadPart>(a => a.PartGroup).Where(a => a.Domain == domain && a.Status == "AC").ToList();
```

SQL Profile shows that all of the fields are being returned including the PartGroup fields from the Include.

When investigating the "data" variable (List) the Part-related fields (including PartGroupCode) are filled out - however, **the PartGroup (which primarily contains PartGroup.Name and PartGroup.Code) are null.**

P.S. - I don't believe this is related but I am also using WebApi however this behavior occurs outside of WebApi as well.

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to number the column `Order` in the Part entity with 0, 1, 2 instead of 0, 0, 1?

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help but perhaps it is more proper regardless of this issue - I thought the order related to the composite keys/foreign keys.  Can anyone confirm this as a sidenote or should it be numbered uniquely across the properties within the entity?

Comment: My understanding is that the `Order` really numbers the columns and it is independent of the `Key` and `ForeignKey` attributes. BTW: Do the `string` values of the associated rows in `Part` and `PartGroup` tables *exactly* match or are there differences regarding small and capital letters, blanks,etc. ?

Comment: They exactly match, I've also tested the partGroup entity with the following: db.PartGroups.ToList() and watched the same named columns bind into PartGroup - however when joining to the parts table via the include, they do not work... I am still wondering if it has something to do with the sharing of Domain on both the composite key foreign key and the composite key.

Comment: Any luck resolving this?  I just ran into the same thing.

Comment: Could you please share a repro for this?